# Foreign key to connect customer and employee table?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

**Employee** with the columns:

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | Address | Salary | Department | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**Customer** with the columns:

| CustomerID | FirstName | LastName | Address | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I also have two other tables:

**Product**:

| ProductID | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |

**Purchase**:

| ProductID | CustomerID | PurchaseDate | Inventory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

This is the query I need to create:

- Employee is Customer Report - Employee Name, Product Purchased,
  Product Cost, Total Purchased For All Products Per Employee

By looking at the data, I already know that all of the customers are also employees. I need to create a foreign key in either the customer table or the employee table in order to write this query. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: If one of the tables is and will be just a subset of the other why keep two tables?

Comment: When an `Employee` is a `Customer`, do the `EmployeeID` and `CustomerID` match? If so, that's already your foreign key. If they don't, how do you determine when a specific `Employee` is a specific `Customer`?

Comment: They don't match unfortunately. Customers are employees based on the firstname, lastname and address

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities. The simplest would be to use the same number for both, in which case you need a mechanism to stop an employees number being used for a customer. A reserved range of numbers would be a simple way.
If not you could add a customer_number column to employees, which would be a foreign key.
For the first three tables, Employee, Customer and Product, the primary key is the ID column. For purchases you need to invent a column as the same employee could buy the same product more than once. An auto increment column as primary key would be simpler. The 2 ID columns are foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> > When an Employee is a Customer, do the `EmployeeID` and `CustomerID` match? If so, that's already your foreign key. If they don't, how do you determine when a specific Employee is a specific Customer?
>
> They don't match unfortunately. Customers are employees based on the firstname, lastname and address

You do not want a foreign key relationship; instead when you display the data you would need to join the tables on the `firstname`, `lastname` and `address`.

```sql
SELECT c.firstname || ' ' || c.lastname AS name
       -- other columns you want to display
FROM   customers c
       INNER JOIN employees e
       ON (   c.firstname = e.firstname
          AND c.lastname  = e.lastname
          AND c.address   = e.address)
       -- and then join the product and purchase tables to get the other data
```

However, when you have `John Smith` and `Joanne Smith` living at the same address and they are both stored in your database as `J Smith` then they will match even though they are not the same person. Or you have one person in the customer table under the name `Joanne Smith` and in the employee table called `Jo Smith` then they will not match, even though they are the same person. Etc.

You want to find a better solution than matching on names and addresses.

> I need to create a foreign key in either the customer table or the employee table in order to write this query.

No, what you really want to do is refactor your tables into third-normal form so that you do not duplicate date and ensure the `id` columns match between `customers` and `employees`; you can do that by including a `people` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
  id        NUMBER(10,0)
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            CONSTRAINT people__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR2(100)
            NOT NULL,
  lastname  VARCHAR2(100)
            NOT NULL,
  address   VARCHAR2(500)
            NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employees (
  id         CONSTRAINT employees__id__pk PRIMARY KEY
             CONSTRAINT employees__id__fk REFERENCES people,
  salary     NUMBER(10,2),
  department NUMBER(5,0),
  position   VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE customers (
  id         CONSTRAINT customers__id__pk PRIMARY KEY
             CONSTRAINT customers__id__fk REFERENCES people,
  company    VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

Then you know if a customer and an employee has the same `id` then they are the same person.